# CountVectorizer - ignore words appearing less then x times and with less then y characters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I'd like to know if there is any way to let `CountVectorizer()` ignore words appearing less than x times in all documents and with less than y characters. Something like the `wordlength` and `bounds` paramenters in `R`'s `DocumentTermMatrix` (`tm`).

Example

This corpus:

```
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
```

Now becomes this:

```
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.toarray())
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

Setting x and y to 2, I'd like to have this:

```
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.toarray())
[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to:

- set `min_df=2` that will take care about `x`
- define `token_pattern=r"(?u)\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b"` that will take care about `y` (you may try `token_pattern=r"(?u)\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,}\b"` to include numbers and underscore in the token definition)

**Demo:**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = [
    "This is the first document.",
    "This document is the second document.",
    "And this is the third one.",
    "Is this the first document?",
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=2, token_pattern=r"(?u)\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b")
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(X.toarray())
```

---

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: @Maurinho Does this answer your question? Was it helpful? If so you may wish to accept/upvote. Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers